# Making Apache Felix Gogo not open a local console

Tags: osgi, apache-felix

I am learning Apache Felix to use as my OSGi framework.  I want to be able to use the Felix Remote Shell to access my running instance through telnet.  The Remote Shell accesses the process through Gogo, as explained on http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-remote-shell.html.  When I start Felix with the Gogo shell bundles in the auto-deploy `bundles` directory, it opens a Felix prompt `g!` on the Linux console from which I am starting.  What I would like to do is have Felix start with the Gogo shell active, but without attaching to my current Linux console and showing the `g!` prompt, and still allowing me to access the instance using the Remote Shell through telnet.  Is this possible?  If so, what is the correct way to do it?  Would `nohup` and running in the background suffice?  That doesn't seem very clean to me.  Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 14):

According to [a discussion on the mailing list](http://apache-felix.18485.n6.nabble.com/Gogo-shell-on-standard-input-output-streams-td4845969.html#a4845970), you should add the `-Dgosh.args=--nointeractive` JVM argument.

Comment: This worked for me. I don't know why this answer has not been accepted. I can think of one valid reason, but that would be real unfortunate for the family of the OP author. :)